# Add an array to json object angularjs

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am trying to add a JSON array to a JSON object. My code is like this

```
$scope.packageElement = {
    "settings": [
        {
            "showNextPallet": true,
            "isParcelData": false,
            "isFreightData": true,
            "name": 0
        }
    ]
};

dataFromServer = {
    "pData": [
        {
            "PKUNIT": "LP",
            "PKDESC": "LARGE PKG",
            "PKDLEN": 30,
            "PKDWDT": 20,
            "PKDHTG": 20
        }
    ]
};

$scope.packageElement.concat(dataFromServer.pData);
```

But this throws an error

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

at line

```
$scope.packageElement.concat(dataFromServer.pData);
```

My desired output is like this

```
var expectedOutPut = {
    "settings": [
        {
            "showNextPallet": true,
            "isParcelData": false,
            "isFreightData": true,
            "name": 0
        }
    ], "pData": [
        {
            "PKUNIT": "LP",
            "PKDESC": "LARGE PKG",
            "PKDLEN": 30,
            "PKDWDT": 20,
            "PKDHTG": 20
        }
    ]
};
```

Can any one point out what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple:

```
$scope.packageElement.pData = dataFromServer.pData;
```

`$scope.packageElement` is an object, it doesn't have a `concat` function.

Or, a better option could be to use [`angular.extend()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend):

```
var expectedOutPut = angular.extend({}, $scope.packageElement, {'pData': dataFromServer.pData});
```

This way, you'll copy the objects, instead of modifying them.
<sub>Note: Keep in mind that angular.extend does not support recursive merge (deep copy).</sub>